# Could not load type 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc.Proxy.MvcControllerProxy' when installing on Sitefinity 8.1.5800

Tags: babaganoush-sitefinity

I am trying to install Babaganoush on Sitefinity 8.1.5800 which has assembly redirects in place. I am getting the exception below and would like to know if anyone else has seen this?

Could not load type 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc.Proxy.MvcControllerProxy' from assembly 'Telerik.Sitefinity, Version=8.1.5800.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc.Proxy.MvcControllerProxy' from assembly 'Telerik.Sitefinity, Version=8.1.5800.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc.Proxy.MvcControllerProxy' from assembly 'Telerik.Sitefinity, Version=8.1.5800.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563'.]
   Babaganoush.Sitefinity.Utilities.ConfigHelper.RegisterToolboxWidget(String title, String description, String cssClass, String resourceClassId, String layoutTemplate, String sectionName, Nullable`1 sectionOrdinal, ToolboxType toolboxType) +0
   Babaganoush.Sitefinity.Mvc.Startup.OnBootstrapperInitialized(Object sender, ExecutedEventArgs e) +704
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Abstractions.Bootstrapper.Bootstrap() +906
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinityHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +400
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +530
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc.Proxy.MvcControllerProxy' from assembly 'Telerik.Sitefinity, Version=8.1.5800.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618692
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458309

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249

Answer (score 0):

The MvcControllerProxy type is now in the Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc assembly.

You'll probably have to wait for the guys at Falafel to release a version that targets Sitefinity 8.1

Comment: Has anyone heard if Falafel is going to support 8.1? I can't find any information on this on the net.

Comment: better email them directly